# Return for function after certain execution time

Tags: javascript, node.js, return, settimeout

Full clarity, I'm doing this in Node if that matters.

I have a method that makes a few synchronous calls (they rely on the feedback of each call in the next, so must be synchronous) and I don't have much control over environment or the things I'm calling.

I need to return a value after a set time (about 3 seconds) whether or not those calls have completed. If those calls have completed, the script finishes and returns the value. A sort of backup timeout that returns an acceptable (if incomplete) value instead of timing out completely due to server execution limits and throwing an error.

I immediately think to use a `setTimeout()` (and a `clearTimeout()` if it's not tripped) to do the return. However, returning a value in the setTimeout callback doesn't end my script and return that value, obviously - so how would I?

```
//"myFunction" being consumed by something I don't have control over
//Otherwise I'd just wrap the caller in a timeout
myFunction = async () => {

    var scripttimer = setTimeout(function(){
        //emergency exit - script took longer than 3 seconds
        return "I need to return a value for myFunction now"; 
    }, 3000);

    //multiple synchronous remote https calls are made
    //right here which could sometimes cause this function
    //to take more than 3 seconds, at which point the 
    //scripttimer should kill myFunction by making it return 
    //a value. That's the part that I'm asking how to do, if 
    //even possible

    if (scripttimer){
        //if we took less than 3 seconds, we don't need the backup 
        //callback in scripttimer and so we're going to kill it
        clearTimeout(scripttimer);
    }

    //best scenario return value, script took less than 3 seconds
    return "did this anyways";
}
```

**Tried**

Thought to do a try-catch-throw setup:

```
try {

    var scripttimer = setTimeout(function(){
        throw "I need to return a value for myFunction now"; 
    }, 3000);

    //wait 4 seconds maybe
    if (scripttimer){
        clearTimeout(scripttimer);
    }
    return "I don't make it out if I take too long";


} catch (e){
    return "acceptable enough";
}
```

... but the catch doesn't catch it, which kinda makes sense since the error thrown is outside the scope of the try-catch since it's asynchronous... so there goes my best idea so far.

Comment: It may help if you included a bit more detail on the function that you want to call asynchronously with a timeout.

Comment: @ctt this function (`myFunction`) is the one being called. What it's doing internally is probably irrelevant, but it's just a few https calls and a bunch of logic around them that sometimes takes too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the delay in `httpCall` function to less than 3 seconds then you will get the output as `hello`

and if the delay in `httpCall` is more than 3 seconds then you will get the output as `bye`

```
// Your Http Call Here which may take 3 seconds or more. eg.5 seconds


function httpCall(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    setTimeout(function(){
        resolve("hello")
    },5000)
  });
}

// your main function where you will be calling sync functions
function operation(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    const timeoutID = setTimeout(function(){
        resolve("bye")
    },3000)
    httpCall().then(result=>{
       clearTimeout(timeoutID)
       resolve(result)
    })
  });
}

// This is how you should call
operation().then((result)=>console.log(result))
```

[Check execution here](https://repl.it/repls/GlamorousStaticScope)

Answer (score 2):

The setTimeout doesn't actually actually works just like the node js event loop does.

With your implementation above, the callback within `setTimeout` will never be called because `clearTimeout` will be executed almost immediately. The setTimeout while counting down will allow the execution of subsequent code within the script which means `clearTimeout` will be called immediately because `scripttimmer` variable is truthy.

Another thing to note is you, should only use `clearTimeout` if you plan on disrupting the `setTimeout` from executing its callback.

You could try an implementation with a callback which will allow you to interact with your return variable like so:

```
const myFunction = async callback => {
    var scripttimer = setTimeout(function(){
        callback("my value");
    }, 3000);

    return "did this anyways";
}

myFunction(val => console.log(val));
```

See execution [here](https://repl.it/@toondaey/setTimeout)

Also, you should avoid using `async` unless you're planning on using an `await` within your function.

Comment: I need the timeout to force `myFunction` to return a value if the rest of the method execution takes more than 3 seconds. Synchronous remote calls between the setting of the timer and the normal return mean it could take more than 3 seconds, or it could take less. Async is a requirement of the calling functionality. I have no control over what is calling this. I want cleartimeout to be called and to not fire the timeout callback if the script takes less than 3 seconds to execute.

Comment: You may try looking into the `setImmediate`  for this. An example is shown [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2265407&seqNum=7)

Comment: neither of those things is in any way related to the OP